# How does iperf calculate throughput

Tags: throughput, iperf

I am trying to calculate ethernet throughput using python (by creating UDP socket). I got throughput in 10-15 MBps range. When I cross verified using iperf, iperf is showing throughput as 35 MBps. 
what logic does iperf use to calculate throughput?
does it use UDP or TCP protocol?

Answer (score 1):

For [iperf2](https://sourceforge.net/p/iperf2/code/ci/master/tree/src/Reporter.c) and UDP (-u) the value is the number of packets * udp payload / time.  If -i is used then interval reports will report per that.  A final report gives the -t value.    For TCP, it's the bytes read / time.

Bob